# Multi delete with only one constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have 3 tables, let's say a, b, c and they all have a column with an ID. The ID corresponds when rows from different tables belong to each other. I want to delete all entries from the tables using an id. I tried the following multi delete:

```
delete from a,b,c from a,b,c where a.id=123;
```

The following wouldn't work

```
delete from a,b,c from a,b,c where a.id=b.id and b.id=c.id and c.id=123;
```

because it is not mandatory to have an element in c when there is one in a and b for a or only in a for a given id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) the syntax is:

```
delete a,b,c 
from a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN c ON a.id = c.id 
where a.id=123;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set up an array and use that to name the tables you want to delete from  each table name that has that ID you are looking for. This way if the id is a foreign key id you will have more control. Run this through a foreach loop.

$table = array(tablea => a, id =>a), array(tableb => b, id => b)

$sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE $where";